# Is there a way to use CSS in Backstage TechDocs?

Tags: html, css, mkdocs, backstage

I'm currently inserting a documentation on our TechDocs in Spotify's Backstage, but since it has a lot of customization, I need to use CSS (either through a separate file or the `<style>` block inside the Markdown file).

I already tried several things, like the `extra_css` property in `mkdocs.yaml`, some markdown extensions like `markdown_include`, `mkdocs-macro-plugins`, `pymdown-extensions`, among others...

I also tried using a HTML file directly and configuring the `mkdocs.yaml` to use it, like this:

```yaml
site_name: 'Tech Guides'
site_description: 'Teste.'

nav:
  - Início: index.html

plugins:
  - techdocs-core
  - kroki
```

Which results only in an endless loading when trying to load the documentation (inspecting the page I can see the HTML in the code though).

Is there a way to do that, or am I trying to achieve something impossible?

Just for the record, change the theme is out of question, it would need to be something at page level.

Answer (score 1):

The setting "requires" that the "index" file has the ".md" extension.

You should limit yourself to using what the markdown provides of resources for efficient use of TechDocs.